# R Studio change pandoc .tex template

Tags: r, pandoc, r-markdown

I want to use a different latex template for rendering R markdown version 2.

I found the following suggestions:

a) location of template

```
system.file("rmd/latex/default.tex", package="rmarkdown")
```

b) change of YAML front matter

```
---
...
output:
   pdf_document:
      template: mytemplate.tex
---
```

However, his does not seem to be the correct template location for R Studio/ Pandoc, as I get the following error message:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not find data file templates\mytemplate.tex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the *style.tex* file in the same folder as the markdown file does now works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I have the answer, the default directory for Pandoc can be found here:

```
system("pandoc -v")
```

If the folder does not exist, create it as well as a subfolder called templates and copy your tex template here.

You can see the original template here:

```
system("pandoc -D latex")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out or not but this may be a useful link. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html
I am finding myself in the same boat as you wanting to create a custom template to output to PDF.

Comment: Further to this installing the rticles package from rstudio is a help. `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rticles")` This showed the path for the package (with resources inside) to be Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rticles/rmarkdown/templates I think from my reading it needs to a separate r package that gets created.